# Porting Android to run on ARM RealView Debugger

Tags: android, arm, porting, trustzone

I am new for Android OS porting. My task is to port Android OS to run in ARM TrustZone Non-secure world. To achieve this, I will first try to port Android OS to run in ARM TrustZone secure world using ARM RealView Debugger.

Is there a recommended tutorial for this kind of tasks? I browsed a little bit and find lots of Internet posts talking about running Linux on ARM RealView Debugger. However, for Android, I only found this page http://arm.com/community/software-enablement/linux.php.
In the "Android" tab, the pre-built U-Boot and Android kernel image are provided, but pre-built root file system is not given. Can anyone kindly give me some suggestions or point me to some useful tutorials? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is a good idea to run android in the secure world. the secure world os is supposed to be a small, lightweight os that runs "trustlets" that handles request from the non-secure os.

the right design should be running android as the rich os in the normal world, and running a secure linux or mobicore in the secure os.